# How to rotate a base map image in Unity by script at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, textures

I have a texture map as a base color map in Unity on an object and would like to rotate this texture at run time for different angles

A solution was that I create different textures rotated using another software and to change the map each time in run time

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just simply rotate the Object where the texture is placed on, on Runtime ?
Like:

```
Quaternion TestRotation = Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z);    
gameobject.transform.rotation = TestRotation
```

Comment: No it won't work. I want to rotate the texture on the object.. not the object itself.

Comment: Ok sorry then,I just thought it would be a simpler Soloution. Maybe doing it per Shader could work, but that would mean that you would have to build/find a shader to do so here is a Link to a Similar answer I hope it helps: [Rotate Texture Link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/rotate-texture.19018/)